# solve a fairly simple equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

this is a really elementary question, my appolgies but I have not studied any math since high school. What is a good method for finding x in this;

```
 p / p-d = x / x-r
```

I got to here (which I'm not sure is correct)

```
 p * (x-r) / p-d = x
```

problem with this is that there is still and x on the left, then i did this:

```
 p * (x-r) / = (p-d) * x
```

then

```
 x-r / ((p-d) * x) / p
 x = (((p-d) * x) / p) + r
```

but still the same problem, possibly I'm using the wrong method? I've completely forgotten any keywords or methods that I could search on google to do with solving this kind of equation? (I'm 29 and havent done this since highschool) thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have $a={x\over x-r}$, then $a(x-r)=x$. Distribute on the left: $ax-ar=x$. Now collect the $x$'s on one side...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you have $$\frac{p}{p-d}=\frac{x}{x-r}$$
and you rearranged it to the form $$p(x-r)=x(p-d)$$
(this is a good idea, generally you want to get rid of division in an expression as fast as possible). Expanding, $$px-pr=px-dx$$
Nicely, the $px$s cancel, leaving $$-pr=-dx \implies x=pr/d$$

Comment: (NB: If $d=0$ then your equation becomes $x=x-r$, from which we cannot deduce the value of $x$.

Comment: perfect thanks, I'd forgotten about taking elements out of brackets

Comment: @DanielLittlewood: You may want to add the case when $d=0$ and $r=0$ :)

Comment: Indeed, if r=0 then we can't deduce x either (it can be anything provided d=0)

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\frac{x}{x-r} &= \frac{p}{p-d} \\
x &= \frac{p}{p-d}(x-r)\\
x &= \frac{p}{p-d}x-\frac{p}{p-d}r\\
x-\frac{p}{p-d}x &= -\frac{p}{p-d}r\\
\left(1-\frac{p}{p-d}\right)x &= -\frac{p}{p-d}r\\
x &= \frac{\frac{p}{p-d}r}{\frac{p}{p-d}-1} \\
x &= \frac{\frac{p}{p-d}r}{\frac{d}{p-d}} \\
x &= \frac{pr}{d}
\end{align*}

Further, you want to check whether that is not equal to $r$ normally, to avoid division by zero, but in this case, that isn't possible. Indeed, $d$ cannot be zero, to avoid division by zero. In that case there are no solutions for $x$, unless we also have $r=0$, in which case there will be infinitely many solutions.

Comment: There's still a good deal of simplification to be made here.

Comment: thanks - for my particular application 'd' will sometimes be zero. Unfortunately it wont let me accept 2 answers

Comment: @user3062260 no problem. As soon as you get 15 reputation, you can upvote any answer you want.